# Set Frame Size in Gorilla Websocket

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am developing an application that uses **gorilla/websocket** framework on the serverside. I have an unusual use-case in which the front-end sends to the back-end a 6.8 MB json. I am receiving the following error:

```
websocket: close 1009 (message too big): Frame size of 3036066 bytes exceeds maximum accepted frame size.
```

I tried calling the following function on the connection but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
// SetReadLimit sets the maximum size for a message read from the peer. If a
// message exceeds the limit, the connection sends a close message to the peer
// and returns ErrReadLimit to the application.
func (c *Conn) SetReadLimit(limit int64) {
    c.readLimit = limit
}
```

If I am not mistaken, this sets the maximum accepted size for a message, not for a frame, that's why the problem still persists.
Do you know any similar way to set the read limit for a frame, so that my 6.8 MB will be accepted by the server?

Comment: The Gorilla package has no limits on the size of received frames other than those imposed by the protocol (the fame size must fit in 63 bits).  The error message in the question was received from the peer.  Is it possible that the application is sending a message with a huge frame to the peer? If so, edit the question to show the code used to send the message.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the right size? Does the problem occur if you remove SetReadLmit from code?

Comment: SetReadLimit does not affect the size of frames sent by the peer.  The error message for breaching the read limit is `websocket: read limit exceeded`, not the message shown in the question.